# Is there an EBCDIC_STR function on IBMi

Tags: sql, db2, ascii, ibm-midrange, ebcdic

I'm running into issue with character encoding and I found the functions `EBCDIC_STR`, `ASCII_STR` in `Db2` for z/OS. Are there similar function for `Db2` for IBM i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with v7.2, there is a similar function in DB2 for i, it is `CHAR`. It is not an exact replacement though. While `EBCDIC_STR` returns a string in the system EBCDIC CCSID, and provides a UTF-16 encoding for unknown characters, `CHAR` takes a string and converts it to a provided CCSID. `CHAR` has no defined behavior for characters that cannot be converted to the new CCSID.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to use a `CAST` specification in your SQL statement, specifying in it the desired CCSID, rather than using a built-in function.

[This documentation page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcast.htm) gives the syntax of a CAST specification, but it does not have a precisely relevant example.  The DB2 for zOS `CAST` page gives an example that should be the same on the i Series:

```
 CAST(MYDATA AS CHAR(10) CCSID 367)
```